# Given $X_1, X_2..$ independent real r.v., say if $\{X_1 X_2, X_1 X_3, X_1 X_4, \ldots \}$ are always independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I have a set of problems about independence of RV which I'm having quite a hard time solving. I think I know the theory, but when it's time to get the hands dirty, I do not know where to begin.
Here is one of them

Given $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ **independent** real r.v., **say if the following proposition is always true or not** $\{X_1 X_2, X_1 X_3, X_1 X_4, \ldots\}$ are independent.
I know that my objective is to prove that
$$
P(\{X_1 X_2, X_1 X_3, X_1 X_4, \ldots\}) = P(X_1 X_2) \cdot P(X_1 X_2) \cdot P(X_1 X_3)\cdots
$$
As the definition of independence. But I do not find the way.
What I tried so far:\

1. Conditioning on $X_1$ like $P(a X_2\mid X_1=a, aX_3\mid X_1=a,\ldots) P(X_1=a)$, given the $X_is$ are independent that factorizes, but i cannot put the "times $X_1$" back into each probability.\
2. Thinking as a cartesian product $P(\{X_1\} \times \{X_2,X_3 \dots \})$, and I couldn't actually elaborate much here.\

I am looking to both: A hint to advance with this one, and maybe some insight on how to address these kind of problems, since I have a few left.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume the $X_i$ are independent to begin with, no?

Comment: Also, by the way you are conditioning the $X_i$ it seems that these are discrete. Is that the case? Otherwise $P(X_i = a)$ will always be zero. (to clarify: I didn't downvote you)

Comment: $P(X_1X_2)$ has no meaning. Why do you assume that all random variables are discrete? Sorry to say that there is too much of nonsense in what you have written. The question itself is absurd since there is no assumption of $X_i$'s.

Comment: Let $X$ be a random variable with, say $N(0,1)$ distribution,  and $X_i=X$ for all $i$. Do you see that this  is a counter-example?

Comment: omg, yes sorry, they are all independent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $P(X_1 X_2)$ for me is the Probability of the Product between $X_1$ and $X_2$. Maybe it's abuse of notation and should say $P(X_1 X_2 \leq a)$ or something? 
And there is no reason to asume they are discrete.
And your counter example does not hold because you're assuming iid, and that is also not necessary true. We only know they are **real and independent**

Comment: I am sorry, I have noted another mistake in the way I wrote the problem. It is not **show that** it is **say if** the following proposition is always true or not. Which changes a lot the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for problems like that, you want to construct a(n) (counter-)example and play around with it.

As a hint, here is a particular random variable to think about: Let $X_1$ be Bernoulli(1/2), that is, it is $0$ with probability 1/2, and $1$ with probability 1/2. Now, construct some $X_i$s for yourself, and then ask questions like "What is the probability that $X_1 X_i = 0$  given $X_1 X_j = 0?$"

As a general problem solving strategy, you should make sure to not have typos in your problem statements (as was outlined in the comment section), because that could be a result of misunderstanding some fundamental concepts. Otherwise, if it is a proof question, try to play with simple examples: it is easier to see why something should be true by looking at smaller examples, and eventually, you will either see a pattern or you will come up with a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, really clear, and I take your recommendations and advice. I still have one final doubt:\
Sometimes I think I'm overthinking the problems. When you say $P(X_1 X_i =0 | X_1 X_j = 0)$ you mean think the $\frac{P(X_1 X_i =0 | X_1 X_j = 0)}{P(X_1 X_j = 0)}$ in some easy cases to have a counter-example, or is there a more direct way of thinking it?

Comment: I was thinking of conditioning by probability that something is 0 because you were multiplying things. Depending on the situation, you will need to look at different examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously untrue.  Consider the case of $X_2 = X_3 = X_4 = ... = 1$ and $X_1 = N(0,1)$.  Then $X_1, X_2, ...$ are jointly independent, but the products are not.